# Skip Currently Playing Song when Dislike Selected in Apple Music

Tags: siri, apple-music

When using Apple Music and a song plays that I don't like, I click "Dislike" but the song continues playing as if I might want to continue to listen to the song. Wow.

If I instead tell Siri "Hey Siri, dislike this song" she will respond "OK. I'll remember that you don't like this song." and will then Skip the song as expected.

Is there a way to make the manual click of "dislike" skip the song?